# angularjs: How to check duplicate row befor pushing new row to json object

Tags: angularjs

I have a json array object `$scope.products= [];` and ng-click function called 
addRow.

I want to perform a check before push new row to array is new row is already exists in array, or not when addRow function is called.

If it already exists, then new row is not push to array.

```
$scope.addRow = function(){
$scope.products.push({'pro_name':$scope.pro_name,'pro_id':$scope.pro_id, 'batch_no': $scope.input_batch_no });
}
```

Comment: Since it is your first question on SO, you might read [the guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Check if it exists already in the array:

```
$scope.addRow = function(){
    var exists = false;
    $scope.products.forEach(product => {
        if (product.pro_name === $scope.pro_name && product.pro_id === $scope.pro_id && product.batch_no === $scope.batch_no) {
            exists = true;
        }
    })
    if (!exists) {
        $scope.products.push({
            'pro_name':$scope.pro_name,
            'pro_id':$scope.pro_id,
            'batch_no': $scope.input_batch_no
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a unique identifier you can check whether the list of added rows includes such element with this identifier.

```
 $scope.addRow = function(product) {

    if($scope.selectedProducts.find(p => p.pro_id === product.pro_id)) {
       return;
    };

    $scope.selectedProducts.push(product);

 }
```

Here's a working [piece of code](https://jsfiddle.net/0pfg4ctx/)